# Input type range slider thumb not moveable in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm working on a web player for video and I've been testing it in Chrome `(Version 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit))` and Firefox`(52.5.2 (64-bit))`. In Chrome whenever I move the slider for searching trough the video, it just jumps back to the current video play time instead of the time the user wants the video to play from.

Here is the function handling this part:

```
function vidSeek(){
    var seekto = vid.duration * (seekbar.value / 100);
    vid.currentTime = seekto;
}
```

This is working as expected in Firefox (however inside firefox there is a stiling problem where ther seems to be default styling overlaying the one I'm writing, but I don't think it has anything to do with it)

Here is the html for the controll bar containing the sliders:

```
<div id="playercontrolls">
    <button id="playpausebtn">Pause</button>
    <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1"> <!-- Seek bar doesn't work-->
    <span id="curtimetext" class="white-text"></span> / <span id="durtimetext" class="white-text"></span>
    <button id="mutebtn">Mute</button>
    <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1"> <!-- Volume bar works-->
    <button id="fullscreenbtn">[]</button>
</div>
```

I've also made a volume slider which seems to be working in both Firefox and Chrome (except for the stiling issue in Firefox)

The code for that is:

```
function setvolume(){
    if(vid.muted && volumeslider.value != 0){
        vid.muted = false;
        mutebtn.innerHTML = "Mute";
    }
    vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;
}
```

Also I'm programmaticly changing the value of the seek bar so it follows the video time like this:

```
function seekTimeUpdate(){
    var nt = vid.currentTime * (100 / vid.duration);
    seekbar.value = nt;

    // update time text
    updateTime();
}

function updateTime(){
    var curmins = Math.floor(vid.currentTime / 60);
    var cursecs = Math.round(vid.currentTime - curmins * 60);
    var durmins = Math.floor(vid.duration / 60);
    var dursecs = Math.round(vid.duration - durmins * 60);

    if(cursecs < 10){ cursecs = "0"+cursecs;}
    if(dursecs < 10){ dursecs = "0"+dursecs;}
    if(durmins > 10)
        if(curmins < 10){ curmins = "0"+curmins;}

    curtimetext.innerHTML = curmins+":"+cursecs;
    durtimetext.innerHTML = durmins+":"+dursecs;
}
```

Again this works fine in both Firefox and Chrome.

CSS for the sliders:

```
input#seekslider {
    width: 90vh;
}

input#volumeslider {
    width: 20vh;
}

input[type='range'] {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background: #000;
    border: #666 1px solid;
    height: 6px;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background: #FFF;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 75%;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

What might be the problem here? Does the styling have anything to do with it's behavior?

**EDIT**: Here is the full javascript code for the player as requested: https://pastebin.com/rM54vqqf

Also here is my HTML for the player part of the page:

```
<div id="playerContainer" class="container z-depth-1">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <video id="vid" autoplay>
                    <source src= "{% static '/TestVideos/'%}{{path}}" type="video/mp4"></source>
                </video>
            </div>
            <div id="playercontrolls">
                <button id="playpausebtn" class="nokit"><i class="fa fa-pause white-text" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <span class="slider"><input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="0.1">    </span>
                <span id="curtimetext" class="white-text"></span> / <span id="durtimetext" class="white-text"></span>
                <button id="mutebtn" class="nokit"><i class="fa fa-volume-up white-text" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <span class="slider"><input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1"></span>
                <button id="fullscreenbtn" class="nokit"><i class="fa fa-desktop white-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Something I've noticed is that whenever I play it in fullscreen the standard controlls act in the same way as my custom controlls (again only in chrome) I've tried to get rid of those custom controlls by doing:

```
::-webkit-media-controls {
  display:none !important;
}

::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
  display:none !important;
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work in full screen. Could there be a problem reguarding CSS that for some reason doesn't allow my javascript to work properly? In that case here is my CSS for the player: https://pastebin.com/FzFjMUPH

Comment: Hello! Could you please present your full code, as this one seems to lack some moments. For instance, I can't see an object `vid` along with `seekbar`. Moreover, it's not entirely understandable how your functions are related to your code. When I added some logical alterations to your example (such as adding a video tag) everything appeared to work fine in Chrome of the same version you mention.

Comment: @OlegSafarov I've added some information which might be helpfull to understanding the problem.

Comment: I created a fiddle with your code, and it seems to work as you intend in Chrome (although your controls don't show up in full screen): https://jsfiddle.net/2jjt3gyo/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seem to have got it (your jsfiddle helped a great deal). There is a conflict when the user is catching the slider and the video is itself moving it automatically according to the events set.

So, I tried out making use of some additional conditions to stop automatic interruptions with the slider when the user is operating it.

Two more variables have been added (`var cursorCaught, onSeeking;`, the last one is set in `function vidSeek()`) along with two more mouse events (`function catchCursor()` for `mousedown` and `function freeCursor()` for `mouseup`) for `seekslider` to set the variables. Finally, there is also a new condition to check in `function seekTimeUpdate()` before making actions: `if (!cursorCaught || onSeeking) { ... }`.

Have a look at this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1y86r593/2/

Perhaps, there might be some side effects because of these new conditions, but the idea should be clear.

Comment: I see what you did there and I'm impressed by the simplicity! It's working well like this however I just need to set it up so the video actually scrolls whenever you drag it (it now just keeps playing until you let go). However I should be able to do this easily!

Answer (score -1):

You can fix it -the easy way!-

replace:

seekbar.addEventListener("change", vidSeek, false);

with:

seekbar.addEventListener("input", vidSeek, false);

I hope it works! Good luck!

**EDIT:**
The proposed solution wasn't working for you, but never give up!

Restore your environment (undo the previous replacement) and then try to:

1) Add a new var on top of your javascript

```
var userIsUpdatingTime = false;
```

2) Let the new var know if the user is interacting with the seekbar

```
   seekbar.addEventListener("input",
    function () {
        userIsUpdatingTime = true;
    }
    ,false);
```

3) Let your seekTimeUpdate know about the new var

```
    function seekTimeUpdate(){
        if (userIsUpdatingTime)
            return;

        var nt = vid.currentTime * (100 / vid.duration);
        seekbar.value = nt;

        // update time text
        updateTime();
    }
```

4) When the update is done update the var!

```
    function vidSeek(){
        var seekto = vid.duration * (seekbar.value / 100);
        vid.currentTime = seekto;
        userIsUpdatingTime = false;
    }
```

5) Let me know if this solution works!

Example paste: https://pastebin.com/rF7F7k23

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm getting the same behavior as before

Comment: what if you replace your seek function with this?

function vidSeek(evt){
    var seekto = vid.duration * (evt.target.value / 100);
    vid.currentTime = seekto;
}

Comment: evt is the event triggered, and this could work because it reads the value when you put it in instead of the value updated by seekTimeUpdate

Comment: are you refreshing your page with ctrl+shift+r? :S i've this working in my browser just now! (chrome 63.0.3239.84 64-bit)

Comment: Yes I am, I've also tried restating chrome after each change but it's not working

Comment: i'm sorry about that... this is the html page i'm using to test https://pastebin.com/0E67NWnB